# Dynamically select / unselect items in event and get data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have 5 circles to click. User can select only one. My problem is that I can't deselect previous circle and remove its `data-value` from variable.

How can I handle it?

HTML

```
<div class="question">
   <h3>' + test + '</h3>
   <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-center"> <span>Całkowicie nietrafnie mnie opisuje</span> </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <div class="circles">
            <div class="numberCircle" data-value="1">1</div>
            <div class="numberCircle" data-value="2">2</div>
            <div class="numberCircle" data-value="3">3</div>
            <div class="numberCircle" data-value="4">4</div>
            <div class="numberCircle" data-value="5">5</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-center"><span>całkowicie trafnie mnie opisuje</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
pinEventAction = function (e) {
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('#progressBar .bar');
    var circles = document.querySelectorAll('.question .circles .clicked');

    if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-value')) {
        values += Number(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
        e.target.className += ' clicked';
        e.target.parentNode.className += ' checked';
        width += 2;
        progressBar.style.width = width + '%';
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains('clicked')) {
        e.target.classList.remove('clicked')
    }
    console.log('score: ' + values);
};

handleClickAndProgressBar = function () {
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('#progressBar .bar');
    var circles = document.querySelectorAll('.question .circles');

    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i].addEventListener('click', pinEventAction);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add an eventListener on each circle, you can add an eventListener to an ancestor node instead. By using `event.target` property, you can determine which node was clicked. Read on [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) for details.

The behavior desired for the circles is like a group of radio buttons that share the same name attribute (only one can be checked). I changed the circles into a radio/label pair then wrapped them into a `<fieldset>` and a `<form>`. By doing this, saves you from writing code for the behavior previously mentioned.

This demo does the following:

- Allows only one active circle
- Allows toggling circles on/off
- Updates value according to what is selected/unselected
- Displays the value

### Demo

```js
var form = document.forms[0];

form.addEventListener('click', circle, false);

function circle(e) {

  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var val = this.elements.view;
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === 'FIELDSET') {
      return;
    }
    if (tgt.classList.contains('act')) {
      tgt.classList.remove('act');
      val.value = 0;
    } else if (!tgt.classList.contains('act')) {
      tgt.classList.add('act');
      val.value = tgt.value;
    }
  } else {
    if (val.value === undefined) {
      val.value = 0;
    }
    return false;
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.rad {
  display: none
}

.l {
  background: black;
  color: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: block;
}

.rad:checked+label.l.act {
  color: cyan
}

.rad:checked+label.l.act::before {
  content: '<'
}

.rad:checked+label.l.act::after {
  content: '>'
}

#view {
  color: tomato;
  font-weight: 900

}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="question">
  <h3>' + test + '</h3>
  <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"> <span>Całkowicie nietrafnie mnie opisuje</span> </div>
    <form class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <output id='view'>0</output>
      <fieldset class="circles">
        <input id='rad1' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value="1">
        <label class="l" for='rad1'>1</label>
        <input id='rad2' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value="2">
        <label class="l" for='rad2'>2</label>
        <input id='rad3' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value="3">
        <label class="l" for='rad3'>3</label>
        <input id='rad4' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value="4">
        <label class="l" for='rad4'>4</label>
        <input id='rad5' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value="5">
        <label class="l" for='rad5'>5</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"><span>całkowicie trafnie mnie opisuje</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that making them a radio group like you did  also simplifies the approach since they already have a concept of only allowing one selected at a time.